# JAVA BigInteger class error: BigInteger: modulus not positive

Tags: java, compiler-errors, biginteger

I made code for getting GCD(Greatest Common Division) between two numbers. 
It's because I am supposed to input number by 19th position, I think I need to use BigInteger Math class. However, after I compile my code I have this error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger: modulus not positive    at
>   java.math.BigInteger.mod(BigInteger.java:2415)    at
>   test.GCD(test.java:9)     at test.GCD(test.java:9)    at
>   test.GCD(test.java:9)     at test.GCD(test.java:9)    at
>   test.main(test.java:22)

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class test {
public static BigInteger GCD(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    if (b.equals(0))
        return a;
    else
        return GCD(b, a.mod(b));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigInteger p = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    BigInteger q = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger z = BigInteger.ONE;
    p = sc.nextBigInteger();
    q = sc.nextBigInteger();

    while (true) {
        if (GCD(p, q).compareTo(i) == -1) {
            System.out.print("1");
        }
        else if(GCD(p, q).compareTo(i) == 0) {
            System.out.print("1");
        }
        else if(GCD(p,q).compareTo(i) == 1) {
            break;
        }
        i.add(z);
    }
}
}
```

There is no grammar error.

Comment: 19 positions could be done with a `long`, which is probably a little easier to use. I guess those 19 positions were actually specified to make you use `long`, since 19 is exactly the maximum number of digits a long can certainly hold.

Comment: I knew the long range is from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. If I am supposed to input 9,999,999,999,999,999,999 it should be an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the base statement

```
if (b.equals(0))
```

which is attempting to compare `BigInteger b` with a boxed integer `0` which obviously isnt equal resulting in `0` fatally being passed as the modulus. You could use

```
if (b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
```